# Contact Google+ friends on behalf of user

Tags: google-plus, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to send a message, on behalf of a user, to a subset of their google+ friends.

- Right now, I can get a list of google+ friends
- Separately I can get a list of their contacts' email addresses.

Is there a way to match up the two? Or is there a better way of sending this message to their contacts?

Comment: Getting the list of friends should allow you to get their emails. The [People Resource](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people#resource) contains that kind of user information.

Comment: @Andy, I've tried this example https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/list#auth  with both "email" and "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read" permissions. It correctly lists my contacts, but no email addresses for them.

Comment: You should be able to get a list of ids with that which you can then pass into [people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get). GET will retrieve a more detailed response which includes email.

Comment: @Andy, thanks for your follow up. I've tried that. And I can, indeed get a more detailed response. Unfortunately email is not one of the fields returned (again using the permissions listed above). Is this something that's working for you?

Comment: When testing with the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get#try-it), I can see emails. It requests for `plus.login`, `plus.me`, `userinfo.email`, and `userinfo.profile` scopes. Perhaps try those scopes or the API explorer to see if you can get a response that contains email?

Comment: I can see emails when the user is "me". But not for another user that I'm connected to... You're seeing emails for others?